# Take top elements from a datatable c#

Tags: c#, .net, ado.net, dataset

I use the following code to take the top element from data and bind it to a repeator

```
rptViewUsers.DataSource = UserLoggingBL.GetAllUsers().AsEnumerable().Take(5);
rptViewUsers.DataBind();
```

where GetAllUsers() return a datatable.

But when I bind it to repeator I get this error

```
 <asp:Label runat="server" Text='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "UserName") %>'></asp:Label>

An exception of type 'System.Web.HttpException' occurred in System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
Additional information: DataBinding: 'System.Data.DataRow' does not contain a property with the name 'UserName'.
```

My aim is to fetch only top 5 rows from a datable and assign it to a repeator.
It works fine when I use this code without taking the top five. All my names are correct.

What am I missing ?

Comment: `with the name...` With the name what? Pretty sure the next part of the error will tell you what's wrong

Comment: As per your update; it seems your query isn't returning rows with a `UserName` column

Comment: Yes.. but it does without this AsEnumerable() part.

Comment: change the `.AsEnumerable()` to `.Cast<[yourRowType]>()`. For example: `UserLoggingBL.GetAllUsers().Cast<UserRow>().Take(5);`. Or, you can change your method `GetAllUsers` to return `IEnumerable<UserRow>` (better solution)